# How do you know you need to define a new method?

Tags: java

We want each method to do a distinct task, right? How do you draw that line?

For example, say I have a class with an int array that I need to have set to certain numbers when the class is constructed. Should I loop through the array right there or make a separate method for what is ultimately a simple task?

Comment: It depends. Do whatever it takes to make your code as readable as possible. Make sure all the code in a method/constructor works at the same level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new method whenever you have a sensible name for one. When you have a good name for a new method, it suggests that what you're doing there is a separate task and potentially reusable.

Note that this is just a rule of thumb and may not apply to all cases. Another rule is to make a new method if your current method is too long (I've heard 48 lines cited as an upper bound).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample class that I hope points out what you are looking for:

```
class Sample {
    private int[] myInts = null;

    // we need a constructor if we are going to pass in stuff
    // if we don't provide a constructor, java will create one for us
    public Sample(int[] inputs) {
        // I can just set this array, I don't need a separate method to 
        // loop through and create a new array and copy the old one.
        myInts = inputs;
    }

    // here we are going to do something discreet, so I need a new method.
    public int add() {
        int returnValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++) {
            returnValue += myInts[i];
        }
        return returnValue;
    } // end my "add()" method
} // end my Sample class
```

Comment: Say I need to create an array, fill it with values, and use it to initialize a field. I feel silly writing setArray(genArray()), should I? I'm also intrigued by the initialization to null. Why the redundancy?

Comment: Initializing to null during declaration prevents a possible problem where the variable is never initialized. This is a simple example, so we can see that that isn't going to happen. No, I don't see any reason that you need to setArray(genArray()) if the array is predetermined eg. an array of primes int[] primes = new {1,2,3,5,7}; but if you want to fill the array with some computations based on user input, you may very well call a method to generate the values, eg. you want to calculate the area of a polygon that the user types in values of the length of sides: int[] polygon = getUserInputs();

Comment: How does that prevent not initializing a value? It'll return null anyway, won't it? _int[] i; print(i);_ Throws a NullPointerException already, isn't setting it null redundant?